# Como criar um clique (toque) automático na tela do Android?

Tags: java, android

sou iniciante e estou tentando fazer um jogo e desejo que automaticamente, durante a execução do app ocorra um clique em área específica da tela, como se o usuário tivesse feito.

1 - Posso simular este clique/toque automaticamente, sem um clique real do usuário?

2 - Se sim, existe alguma forma de tornar o clique/toque na tela aleatório?

desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            "View touched", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
        toast.show();

        return true;
    }
});


// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Você pode gerar números aleatórios com a classe `Random` do Java.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android